# Trouble writing to 4D vector in C++ (no viable overloaded '=')

Tags: c++, vector

The issue I am facing is that via the openCV library I am reading in a series of images as their own "Mat" format: an image matrix.
Basically I need to write any pixel value that's > 0 as "true" to a 4D vector and any that == 0 as "false".

Why 4 dimensions?
    `vector<vector<vector<bool>>>pointVector;`
The 3 vector levels refer to X,Y,Z axes. Bool is just the true/false. The images are Y by Z and are stacked in 3D along axis X.
Basically we have a series of images representing points that are stacked in 3D.
(Poor explanation? Probably)
Anyway, the issue comes in my function to read the points in a single photo then write them out to the 4D vector.

Note: xVal is a global storing the ID number of the photo addressed. It's used for the X dimension (layers of images).

```
 Int lineTo3DVector (Mat image)
 {
      // Takes in matrix and converts to 4D vector.
      // This will be exported and all vectors added together into a point cloud

      vector<vector<vector<bool>>>pointVector; 
      for (int x=0; x<image.rows; x++)
      {
           for (int y = 0; y<image.cols; y++)
           {
                if((image.at<int>(x,y)) > 0)
                {
                     pointVector[xVal*image.cols*image.rows + x*image.cols + y] = true;
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

I haven't finished writing all of the function because  the if statement intended to write pointVector at address xVal, x, y with bool 'true' throws up an error saying:

```
 No viable overloaded '='
```

Any idea what's going wrong? I've scoured the web and given myself a headache trying to dig up info (yeah, noob in the deep-end again) so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess what you are asking is why the compiler tells you it can't convert a `bool` to a `vector<vector<bool>>`. That because you are trying to assign a `bool` to `pointVector[some_index]`, which by the definition of `pointVector` would be `vector<vector<bool>>`. Consider replacing the definition with just `vector<bool> pointVector` and indexig it the way you did, or index it as `pointVector[x][y][z]`. Also what you've declare is 3 dimensional, not 4 dimensional.

Comment: You'll need to resize all of your vectors to correct address them of course.  Now some might call me a curmudgeon but I find these multi-vector constructs absolutely horrific.  I would prefer Boost Multidimensional Array library over std any time for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks Mr Aroosi, I'll have to read that a few more times to make sure I'm getting my head around it completely. I assumed that it was 4D as each vector is a dimension and the boolean is technically a dimension, isn't it?

Comment: @RustyX std::vector<bool> is usually specialized to use 1 bit per bool, at least in most implementations.

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing only the first vector (the outer one), without actually accessing any of the vectors inside.

The syntax would be `pointVector[x][y][z] = true`, where `x`, `y` and `z` are the values you want to use to access the three nested vectors.

What you want is:

```
pointVector[xVal][x][y] = true
```

What you were using is a way to access a 3D array that is laid out in memory as a 1D array, but it's not what you want in your case.

### Make sure you don't go out of bounds

Make sure the elements you are accessing actually exist! If the code you have shown is the actual code, `pointVector` will have no elements when you try to use it.

To fix that, you have to `resize` all the vectors (outer and inner). This can get cumbersome, and you may want to go with the 1D approach, i.e. allocate a large, one-dimensional `bool` array and access it using the method you were using (`largeArray[xVal*image.cols*image.rows + x*image.cols + y]`).

### 1D approach

In the following code `numberOfValues` is the maximum number of elements you will access.

```
int lineTo3DVector (Mat image)
{
      // Takes in matrix and converts to 4D vector.
      // This will be exported and all vectors added together into a point cloud

      std::vector<bool> pointVector;
      pointVector.resize(numberOfValues); 

      for (int x=0; x < image.rows; x++)
      {
           for (int y = 0; y < image.cols; y++)
           {
                if(image.at<int>(x,y) > 0)
                {
                     pointVector[xVal*image.cols*image.rows + x*image.cols + y] = true;
                }
           }
      }

      // Return whatever.
}
```

Comment: some nitpicking: "You're accessing only the first vector (the outer one), without actually accessing any of the vectors inside."  Actually `pointVector[index]` does access the `vector<vector<bool>>` that is an element of `pointVector`, while the `pointVector` is what I would call the "outer one"

Comment: @tobi303 It may be a bad choice of words from my part (sorry, not a native English speaker). What I meant by "accessing a vector X" was "access X to obtain an element from it".

Comment: if I knew better words I would write my own answer :P. I sometimes find it helpful to write it as `pointVector->operator[](index);` because imho then it is more clear what method is called and by this also what is the return type: `pointVector->operator[]` has to return a vector<vector<bool>>. Nevermind, nothing worth a downvote ;)

Comment: Question, though... I thought the address in square brackets [] was the address we were writing to and included all the levels. Why does it take 3 sets of square brackets like that? I thought As it was {X contains {Y contains {Z contains bool}}} as it were, that the address all went in the same bracket. If that makes any sense, I'd be better drawing a diagram of what I mean.

Comment: @AcrimoniousMirth You have a vector that contains a vector that contains another vector. To access elements of a vector, you use the syntax vector[index]. Since the elements of your outer vector are vectors, pointVector[index] is a vector, so you index it as well pointVector[index][anotherIndex]. And so on. Also it's not an address, it's an index. Vectors are contiguous arrays.

Comment: @Banex, thank you, I began to grasp the difference while mulling it over. And thanks, I didn't know the correct word, I'll try and remember it as an index :)

Comment: @Banex I suppose it's sort of like [] tells the vector "open this one" so I was thinking it would be [open this X and while in here open Y then open the Z inside and while in there grab the Boolean] whereas its more like [open X], ol, now what? [open Y]. Ok, now what? [open Z and retrieve Boolean] if you'll excuse the horrendous analogy!